# Unobtrusive validation, MVC and Kendo - Textbox

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo doesn't offer regular old textbox (input) widget.

If unobtrusive validation is turned on and I have a model with a textbox that has the RequiredAttribute on it:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

the Kendo validator ignores the unobtrusive attributes generated by the RequiredAttribute (the regular required attribute does work).

How is one supposed to get the Kendo validator to respect the unobtrusive attributes on inputs not generated by the Kendo server widgets without having to resort to writing custom rules?

Comment: You don't need a Kendo UI Textbox widget because having one is nonsensical. A simple `<input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: myProperty" required />` should work, shouldn't it? Are you using straight HTML/JavaScript or the ASP.NET Helper Classes, like `@Html.Textbox()`?

Comment: I was using the htmlhelpers. I supposed I could just pass into the overload the properties you are suggesting. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yea, you should only need to do something like this, `@Html.Textbox("MyProperty", MyProperty, new { @class = "k-textbox" })` and the unobtrusive validation script _should_ apply the `required` attribute to the input element.

Comment: I'm currently not working on that project anymore but will try it when I get a chance.

Comment: Can this question be closed?